# Unity Audio is slightly delayed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio, delay, audio-source

I want to make a game based on rythm and music. But when prototyping i got stuck at one problem

**When i click the mouse, a sound should play instantly. I analysed a recording - and the sound is about 0.1 second delayed.**

i also tried just visually, and there is no delay - so input lag is not the issue.

I tried several import-options for the audio. but there is always this delay that ruins my concept. Is there any way around this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Impossible to know the root cause from just this information, but my guess would be that either your sound file has some "dead air" with no sound in the beginning of it or your input code is causing the delay somehow.

Comment: @DeclanMcKelvey-Hembree no dead air, and the input works instantly when changing the color of a material. Just the audio source seems to lag behind